# Java SSO windows AD spring4 - Negotiate Header was invalid:

Tags: java, linux, spring, tomcat, single-sign-on

Hi I am trying to setup SSO with JAVA and spring. To do this I'm using this document: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/
and code from paragraph 3. Spnego Negotiate.

But it's not working I get error:

```
org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter doFilter
WARNING: Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate YIIGywYGKwYBBQUCoIIGvzCCBrugMDAuBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHgYKKwYBBAGCNwICCqKCBoUEggaBYIIGfQYJKoZIhvcSAQICAQBuggZsMIIGaKADAgEFoQMCAQ6iBwMFACAAAACjggTtYYIE6TCCBOWgAwIBBaENGwtCSVVSTy5MT0NBTKIiMCCgAwIBAqEZMBcbBEhUVFAbD3ZtaS5iaXVyby5sb2NhbKOCBKkwggSloAMCARehAwIBDqKCBJcEggSTURM5n5gBXc6mVdBmyns4DHBkvw0gqD1GxkYQQx8dWb/upu5sopCPZoxsir970evZKg6/3iDSOyQuGDzjK1xl0Sqma+VNy4ZB9bA5RVCFMZqQT2poicYhaKQbkjazG6GeGUYh7NS91g9qqLXYXtI+jeoOPIDwMCAjaEuq4bRN/JqOIZFLinK2qwEM7h62kRVoqF48cxVHdG+chwLzHCSorp1+ZimU00nkdLk/WjDd88Om1K++735m2JsvGV4h5eSYiZ19fDF5fpbyDOMk4k2g26IuNeg8VNZhC2MjEi47IiteDu+gJKUopjmv1PZ26rtNL78Oawygcxk9F2uIBUoOsCX0S9Nl2aNjfzIxWPlQ0w4kwFCDmsdbzEHD7mfZhNIWQd0CJEhJ+6lrxAXGM7nq86kcFXVE/329G9/HiRtTrnHTwCF4AJCMt4im2OaEjFewgRQZwOqxT72/bGLsbOxYws6Qj0pVJhiXhmRDJiirfjXSzevMp1NANgrfQmlFD+W/d2lY8gPLNQmGGNwmY5TQcdngsxI7ALVB1v8acegka+9AxO3b+ElypvjePVbhZYH6t6AcJlwu4M7Kka94zDtA0ZTWBLmUCHEh8e470zMj+H8kUo6gKSDe+tOrtEjmlGHEiJbg2w/0BcpVUtBqmMTeq7Vf0UvGwBK7JZy6GdWJTDMYpJUD+8w9UEb+GTWCEDfboQcxCIs8ny6qKK8e92BvIrYgm2jAZM2y4VsOSdfPb21bYHhJybtDVvlLpAVlCY/L0NvcIgNWTdi8UCD7OfROCqqjU2B+eftR+1vmhzb7PT/tDm8TXHFcLyNE7W5W/Tp1ncRpq1T7nWbdmefZe8StyfcmxvOje1uMNShWNY3yJFFUUHKsxuz5mvH4tklaPFof7VW1PNTAqAimdCNRIBoWBg7FSKcBnsqOnJoNv8qpvN9nLDwOTlMt3aIREgUxFgLBx2kvU1GbsbhGk10MWZqz/23Xz8BKPmZrE4cTDyCUasKp+7VOkGLDtVtxnLM1vQE1AD8pDRRkrF/EaK3fTNvpsV2dTIzFjFSS89HOGTH8TuNMcnAfFJcn/FRgEI/BJQLDSNB3MRfR+2CwmOaB1rB+iYthTDnd965Y4GpKfE7PpYrYrPiXznZ+oG2JFt/KwGuPAp54x68PgbFNyi+g5fixfsn9o0iGo8UNn6XRNMpZT55jODkIEATZhDWIpPsDMvOnc0wIYZt2Trc0K+By/drx+hfMYNgFnLCoJZOIbjEEneYKbBdkxeVKjUrHILzucfYSu+Eq5He6r9fHTDkHOR23Bn7PmQGZQ8gu7zP7NQE7qvABA8Le4TPWmBGVmnZqYJKlyufFMUmIIuosx6Fe/pBV9+L+fMPuGcbUgFINvYWHavKk3fWWHyfS+bWhphZxoCQ59HpfvVQ4lCvAnd8c5s/tEVgD+1Sek84zRVh76cCsYa/6ybCNKeHveEJJGcZ6mX7KT3EVzByifgTskk1vieYIoPGCoB67x/h8gZDDXiFboSwNIrXCu2qL5WKuAAAr1eyfh6i+zQC5Nw1SoTggdFE0hmLeCqSCAWAwggFcoAMCAReiggFTBIIBT5hccN26LqNklPkMvzsPMEa1y0OIs/pZHZG8ZvCpgxLmu2wpPpt9F2hy+sXsBgI63x/ZzS6z6omPMM8g1PdDjUQazYvSly3LKY7I/FX8sq1pRjtXqm0bG5UMk9pcB9t38jpYW/XwZvACJava+6kmyZxiK/jG8yMrsHokmEnIKUu7TPMgFxkBqJx7yZU63LYp55jlyX+eWnGYC533pjB1nsWMKy5uMUbYungzrj6qB/q4OMaUNmApNX0OSCPjNYOm0ruvA/A2F7ZuoBSkiztTWgRsuPQuyFE0cU1naqjmVllFEX8ThCXxYwjigU6Ms5mQ6HYddCXSFE5/LCSqafJAj4v3CNmefvUNez+dK/ibzPjiGGYQMaZHtrRgLtierTdAmelHIU8wkl5OOOePYLjqUMUVZMA3V+4Eb5nv1eyGI44ltdCNfJME/OEYecl+ICC1
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: GSSContext name of the context initiator is null
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:165)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:152)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:67)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:64)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:456)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:145)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My setup is:

Server: Windows Server 2012 R2
Client: windows 8.0
Java server: Tomcat 8 on debian
All machines are in virtual box only with internal network.

---

**Windows server setup:**

IP:10.0.0.1

to DNS was added vmi.biuro.local

also set spn for account:

```
setspn -A HTTP/vmi.biuro.local vmi
```

Keytab file was generated by this command (under windows server), also trying without /kvno:

```
ktpass /out c:\wrzuta\vmi.keytab /mapuser vmi@BIURO.LOCAL /princ HTTP/vmi.biuro.local@BIURO.LOCAL /pass ZAQ!2wsx /ptype KRB5_NT
_PRINCIPAL /crypto All /kvno 0
```

---

**Linux tomcat server:**

IP:10.0.0.3

Under linux machine i can use keytab file to kinit:

```
root@debian:/# kinit -kt vmi.keytab HTTP/vmi.biuro.local@BIURO.LOCAL
root@debian:/# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: HTTP/vmi.biuro.local@BIURO.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
17.07.2015 10:06:03  17.07.2015 20:06:03  krbtgt/BIURO.LOCAL@BIURO.LOCAL
        renew until 18.07.2015 10:06:03
```

---

**Client:**

IP:10.0.0.2

In internet explorer i added domain to trusted sites.
While i browse secure content in browser it shows up basic auth login form, when I type valid account details i get error mentioned above.
When i hit cancel in basic auth popup i get html login form and when i type correct data i login successful and under the log i have:

```
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab false doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is false principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
                [Krb5LoginModule] user entered username: grzesiek

principal is grzesiek@BIURO.LOCAL
EncryptionKey: keyType=17 keyBytes (hex dump)=0000: 4B 83 C0 91 5E E5 73 6E   01 3B 2C BC E9 56 DA B1  K...^.sn.;,..V..

EncryptionKey: keyType=16 keyBytes (hex dump)=0000: D5 E3 D0 F4 19 7A FB 94   E6 E5 B0 2A C8 2C 75 1A  .....z.....*.,u.
0010: 98 76 97 E3 70 9D A4 46                            .v..p..F

EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=0000: 83 ED 52 4F AE E6 25 B9   40 6A B5 DE D4 7D 4A 21  ..RO..%.@j....J!

Added server's keyKerberos Principal grzesiek@BIURO.LOCALKey Version 0key EncryptionKey: keyType=17 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: 4B 83 C0 91 5E E5 73 6E   01 3B 2C BC E9 56 DA B1  K...^.sn.;,..V..


                [Krb5LoginModule] added Krb5Principal  grzesiek@BIURO.LOCAL to Subject
Added server's keyKerberos Principal grzesiek@BIURO.LOCALKey Version 0key EncryptionKey: keyType=16 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: D5 E3 D0 F4 19 7A FB 94   E6 E5 B0 2A C8 2C 75 1A  .....z.....*.,u.
0010: 98 76 97 E3 70 9D A4 46                            .v..p..F


                [Krb5LoginModule] added Krb5Principal  grzesiek@BIURO.LOCAL to Subject
Added server's keyKerberos Principal grzesiek@BIURO.LOCALKey Version 0key EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: 83 ED 52 4F AE E6 25 B9   40 6A B5 DE D4 7D 4A 21  ..RO..%.@j....J!


                [Krb5LoginModule] added Krb5Principal  grzesiek@BIURO.LOCAL to Subject
Commit Succeeded

                [Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout
                [Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, the `krb5.conf` Kerberos configuration file must be either available at `/etc/krb5.conf` location or the path should be passed using 
`-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/path/to/krb5.conf` option.

Answer (score 2):

I get this configuration working yesterday :)
It looks like that were some bug because after updating libraries everything works correctly.
On linux i have correctly configured krb5.conf in /etc/krb5.conf becouse kinit accepts key.

Not working libraries:

```
spring-security-kerberos-client-1.0.0.RELASE.jar
spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.RELASE.jar
spring-security-kerberos-web-1.0.0.RELASE.jar
```

Working libraries:

```
spring-security-kerberos-client-1.0.1.RELASE.jar
spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.1.RELASE.jar
spring-security-kerberos-web-1.0.1.RELASE.jar
```

All environment was the same at first post.

Comment: I'm having the exact same exception, but I'm using spring-security-kerberos-client-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar and spring-security-kerberos-web-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar. I guess it was not the root cause for your specific issue. Any help would be appreciated.